# Spring Boot @Cacheable stopped working after I moved method to the same class

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I am doing a bit of refactoring in my project and I am facing really weird problem.

I have this service class which is taking care of fetching and parsing data from API. Before refactoring, I had special class only for this cache method and now I moved it here but it suddenly stop working. (When I set a breakpoint inside cache method, it is summoned every time I call this method, before, it was summoned only for the first time, than it returns value from cache)

Here is my service class:

```
    private static final String TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS = "transportLocations";
    private static final String CACHE_MANAGER = "cacheManager";
    private static final String ROOT_METHOD_NAME = "#root.methodName";
    private static final int FALLBACK_TIMEOUT = 1000;

    ...

    @Override
    public List<TransportLocation> fetchAllTransportsLocations() throws Exception {
        final var bodyStructure = createTransportLocationBody();
        final String body = buildBody(bodyStructure);
        final String url = transportLocationApiUrl + getCurrentTimeStamp();
        final HttpResponse<String> response = getTransportsLocations(url, body);
        if (isResponseBad(response.statusCode())) {
            LOG.error(GET_TRANSPORT_LOCATION_BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            return createEmptyList();
        }
        return mapTransportsLocationsResponse(response.body());
    }

    @Cacheable(value = TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS, cacheManager = CACHE_MANAGER, key = ROOT_METHOD_NAME, sync = true)
    private HttpResponse<String> getTransportsLocations(final String url, final String body) throws Exception {
        HttpResponse<String> response = httpService.sendPostRequestWithBody(url, body);
        if (isResponseBad(response.statusCode())) {
            response = handleBadRequest(url, body);
        }
        return response;
    }

    private HttpResponse<String> handleBadRequest(final String url, final String body) throws Exception {
        LOG.error(GET_TRANSPORT_LOCATION_CACHE_BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Thread.sleep(FALLBACK_TIMEOUT);
        return httpService.sendPostRequestWithBody(url, body);
    }
```

Here is my cacheConfig class

```
    @Bean
    public net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager ehCacheManager() {
        final CacheConfiguration transportLocationCache = new CacheConfiguration();
        final net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration config = new net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration();

        transportLocationCache.setName(CACHE_NAME);
        transportLocationCache.setMaxEntriesLocalHeap(ENTRIES_LOCAL_HEAP);
        transportLocationCache.setMemoryStoreEvictionPolicy(LRU);
        transportLocationCache.setTimeToLiveSeconds(TTL_SECONDS);
        config.addCache(transportLocationCache);

        return net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(config);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
    }
```

Do you have any idea, what could be wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe this post can answer yours as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115996/spring-cache-cacheable-method-ignored-when-called-from-within-the-same-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When having a look into Cacheable source, doc says:

```
Annotation indicating that the result of invoking a method (or all methods in a class) 
can be cached.
Each time an advised method is invoked, caching behavior will be applied, checking 
whether the method has been already invoked for the given arguments.
```

The most relevant part of this snippet for this question, is `advised method`. In order to make AOP work, you'll need to organize the code as you did before.

Explanation of why private methods cannot be used with AOP:

```
Because private methods are not inherited by subclasses, i.e. there is no way to 
intercept a private method and then delegate to it because the subclass cannot even 
call that method. This is a normal Java limitation and has nothing to do with AOP specifically.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59961404/14072498

The link provided by Pablo explains why calling method cannot reside in same class as method annotated with `Cacheable`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I moved this logic back to the extra class and it works just fine. Thank you for your time!